# Casimir effect and law of conservation of energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, casimir-effect

If we use a couple of plates and the casimir force attracts those plates, when the plates are close together, we reduce the surface area of the plates by pushing it downwards and then pull the plates away, there is a net postive energy as Casimir force is constant per unit area. Why doesn't this work?